# dismissing the keyboard on UIAlertController UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

normally `view.endEditing(true)` always removes the keyboard in swift on iOS.

however this is not always true, like when the `UITextField` is part of a `self.present()`'ed modal `view` i.e. a form inside a `UIAlertController`

Example

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: _title, message: "Choose", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let numberLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y:0, width:90, height:20))
    numberLabel.textColor = .black
    numberLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    numberLabel.font = UIFont(name: titleLabel.font.fontName, size: 16)
    numberLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: titleLabel.font.pointSize)
    numberLabel.text = "Quantity"

    let quantityField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x:100, y:0, width:140, height:25))
    quantityField.layer.borderWidth = 1
    quantityField.keyboardType = .numberPad
    quantityField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    quantityField.delegate = self
    self.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard(textField: quantityField)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

now in this `self.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard` method I have this nifty code

```
func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard(textField: UITextField){
    let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:320, height:50))
    doneToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default

    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewControllerDisplay.doneButtonAction(_:)))

    let items = NSMutableArray()
    items.add(flexSpace)
    items.add(done)

    doneToolbar.items = items as? [UIBarButtonItem]
    doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

    textField.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
}

@objc func doneButtonAction(_ btn: UIBarButtonItem){
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

the purpose of all this is so that a "Done" keyboard button appears. It does. In fact it looks great, I can also capture the `doneButtonAction()` event which is great, but I am only capturing the `UIBarButtonItem` so I can't use `UITextField.resignFirstResponder()` method, even though I know it will work. I have to use "view"

What I want to do is call `alert.endEditting(true)` but I've tried cycling through the subviews, screening for any occurrences of `UIAlertController` but `self.present` doesn't work that way

Can anyone help me clear this keyboard off the alert view?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by getting the topMost view Controller, and calling `endEditing(true)` I think this question should remain up it's quite a useful titbit for someone one day

```
@objc func doneButtonAction(_ btn: UIBarButtonItem){
    if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
        topController.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```